# Multi Dimensional Array - google.visualization.arrayToDataTable

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, google-visualization

I am having trouble passing a multidimensional array to `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`
to draw a google Chart.

My Array is as follows, c(1-5) and a(1-5) are integers.

```
MultiArray = new Array(6);
MultiArray [0] = new Array(3);
MultiArray [0][0] = 'SLA';
MultiArray [0][1] = 'CV';
MultiArray [0][2] = 'AV';
MultiArray [1] = new Array(3);
MultiArray [1][0] = 'Long List Candidates';
MultiArray [1][1] = c1;
MultiArray [1][2] = a1;
MultiArray [2] = new Array(3);
MultiArray [2][0] = 'Call-in/Book-in Candidate';
MultiArray [2][1] = c2;
MultiArray [2][2] = a2;
MultiArray [3] = new Array(3);
MultiArray [3][0] = 'Interview Candidate';
MultiArray [3][1] = c3;
MultiArray [3][2] = a3;
MultiArray [4] = new Array(3);
MultiArray [4][0] = 'Candidate Reference Call';
MultiArray [4][1] = c4;
MultiArray [4][2] = a4;
MultiArray [5] = new Array(3);
MultiArray [5][0] = 'Shortlist Candidate';
MultiArray [5][1] = c5;
MultiArray [5][2] = a5;

var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(MultiArray);
```

The data does go through but when I use it to draw the Chart it gives me an error:
*"All series on a given axis must be of the same data type".*

I am using the chart:

```
var chart7 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('c7'));
```

I have tried to change all the values to Integers, but then it refuses to go past the `arrayToDataTable` function.

Answer (score 0):

seems to work fine here...

are you sure c(1-5) and a(1-5) are integers?

if any are strings, simply missing, or out of scope, the chart will throw an error

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart', 'table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var c1 =  1;
  var a1 =  2;
  var c2 =  3;
  var a2 =  4;
  var c3 =  5;
  var a3 =  6;
  var c4 =  7;
  var a4 =  8;
  var c5 =  9;
  var a5 = 10;

  var MultiArray = new Array(6);
  MultiArray [0] = new Array(3);
  MultiArray [0][0] = 'SLA';
  MultiArray [0][1] = 'CV';
  MultiArray [0][2] = 'AV';
  MultiArray [1] = new Array(3);
  MultiArray [1][0] = 'Long List Candidates';
  MultiArray [1][1] = c1;
  MultiArray [1][2] = a1;
  MultiArray [2] = new Array(3);
  MultiArray [2][0] = 'Call-in/Book-in Candidate';
  MultiArray [2][1] = c2;
  MultiArray [2][2] = a2;
  MultiArray [3] = new Array(3);
  MultiArray [3][0] = 'Interview Candidate';
  MultiArray [3][1] = c3;
  MultiArray [3][2] = a3;
  MultiArray [4] = new Array(3);
  MultiArray [4][0] = 'Candidate Reference Call';
  MultiArray [4][1] = c4;
  MultiArray [4][2] = a4;
  MultiArray [5] = new Array(3);
  MultiArray [5][0] = 'Shortlist Candidate';
  MultiArray [5][1] = c5;
  MultiArray [5][2] = a5;

  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(MultiArray);

  var chartCol = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_col'));
  chartCol.draw(data);

  var chartTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div_table'));
  chartTable.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div_col"></div>
<div id="chart_div_table"></div>
```